# How to have this const-corrected?

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness, stdset

I have a const-correctness problem which I don't seem to be able to resolve. Here is the structure of my program:

```
class Node
{
    private:
        int            id;
        std::set<Node*> neighbours;
    public:
        Node();
        Node(int id_p);

        void set_id(const int& id_p);
        int  get_id() const;
        void add_neighbour(Node* neighbour);
        bool is_neighbour(Node* neighbour) const;

        friend bool operator <(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs);
};

class Graph
{
    private:
        std::set<Node> node_list;
    public:
        Graph();

        void        add_node(int id);
        const Node* get_node_by_id(int id) const;
        bool        has_node(int id) const;
        void        check_add_node(int id);
        void        add_edge(int id_1, int id_2);
        bool        has_edge(int id_1, int id_2) const;
        void        check_add_edge(int id_1, int id_2);

        (...)
};
```

Now the thing is, if I call the function `Graph::get_node_by_id()`, I want to return a pointer to a given node (type `Node`). But it seems impossible to do so, because the `std::set` implicitly converts my Node type objects to `const Node` objects, and I am unable fetch a `non-const pointer` from a `const` object.

However, I cannot have everything else set to `const Node` (which would resolve the problem), because  I want to call `Node::add_neighbour()` from `Graph::add_edge()`, but whenever I do so, my compiler says that I might be violating the `const`ness (required to have a sorted set) of the elements in the `node_list` set, even though I defined the `less operator<` to only care about the `id`.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this dilemma (without giving up on having a sorted set)? Thank you for your responses!

More info on the error:

If I use non-constant fields, error in `Graph::get_node_by_id()`:

```
for(Node& element : this->node_list) // Error: element should be const Node&
{
    if(element->get_id() == id)
    {
        return element;
    }
}
return nullptr;
```

If I use constant fields, error in `Graph::add_edge()`:

```
(...)
const Node* node_1 = this->get_node_by_id(id_1);
const Node* node_2 = this->get_node_by_id(id_2);
node_1->add_neighbour(node_2); // Error for disregarding constness
node_2->add_neighbour(node_1);
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to have a `map<int, Node>` mapping IDs to nodes, rather than a set.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not keep the internal set as mutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that you have two different 'value semantics' to `Node`.

One is that exposed by `operator<` which is not affected by `add_neighbour`. This is the one `set` needs, to keep things ordered, and which it enforces by making `Node` `const`.

The other is that exposed by the class API, where both `set_id` and `add_neighbour` would change the value.

To keep your sorted `set`, you must not allow the id of a node to change once it's in the set. But you *can* allow the neighbours to change.

So I'd suggest you make the `neighbours` `set` `mutable`, make `add_neighbour` `private` and `const`, and make `Graph` a `friend` of `Node`.

This is what `mutable` gives you, data members that are not part of the 'value' of a type. Note that this means you are indicating that something holding a `const Node*` may expect the result of `is_neighbour` to change between calls.

So...

```
class Node
{
    private:
        // Trust Graph not to mess directly with these!
        int            id;
        mutable std::set<Node*> neighbours;

        friend class Graph;
        // For Graph's exclusive use
        void add_neighbour(Node* neighbour) const;


    public:
        Node();
        Node(int id_p);

        void set_id(const int& id_p); // Callable when not in Graph's set
        int  get_id() const;
        void add_neighbour(Node* neighbour);  // Callable when not in Graph's set
        bool is_neighbour(Node* neighbour) const;

        friend bool operator <(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs);
};

class Graph
{
    private:
        std::set<Node> node_list;
    public:
        Graph();

        void        add_node(int id);
        const Node* get_node_by_id(int id) const;
        bool        has_node(int id) const;
        void        check_add_node(int id);
        void        add_edge(int id_1, int id_2);
        bool        has_edge(int id_1, int id_2) const;
        void        check_add_edge(int id_1, int id_2);

        (...)
};
```

Now what you have is public, non-const mutators for `Node` instances that aren't in `Graph`'s `set`, and an extra mutator for `Graph` to use to change the neighbours of the `Node`s in its `set`.

So only `Graph` can do

```
const Node b;
b.add_neighbour(nullptr);
```

If you really don't trust `Graph`, you can replace the `private` `const` `add_neighbour` with an inner `class`, with a `static add_neighbour(Node* node, Node* neighbour` method, since an inner `class` is implicitly able to access private data of the outer class.

```
class NeighbourHelper {
    friend class Graph;
    static void add(const Node* node, Node* neighbour) {
        node->add_neighbour(neighbour);
    }
```

Now only `Graph` can do

```
const Node b;
Node::NeighbourHelper::add(&b, nullptr);
```

In both cases, the following works for everyone:

```
Node a;
a.add_neighbour(nullptr);
```

---

At this point, you should be suffering a code-smell... The issue is the `public` `get_node_by_id` method in Graph. You actually probably want to expose an iterator of some kind instead, rather than than the raw `Node*`, and make `Node` a private inner class of Graph.

Or even just replace the whole `Node` concept with `std::map<int,std::set<int>>`...

But it depends on your actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

Although TBBle's analysis is correct, there's a much simpler solution: replace Graph's `std::set<Node>` with `std::map<int,Node>`.

Your current `Graph::get_node_by_id()` is using a linear search because `set` doesn't really provide the lookup you want. Making the key external allows you to remove the `operator<` overload and still get a faster and more natural lookup: `map.find(id)`.

The only ugly part is that now your `Node` has an internal id which must match an external key. If you never use the id except to look up a node in the map, you could just remove this entirely. If you need to follow the graph edges (neighbours) and then check the ID, you can replace your set of pointers with a set of map iterators, like:

```
typedef std::map<int, Node> NodeMap;
typedef std::set<NodeMap::iterator> NeighbourMap;
```

Then your traversal has the `pair<const int,Node>` available.

---

NB. on reflection, changing from set to map produces almost the same distinction as TBBle's answer: you split the Node into const and mutable parts. The lookup is cleaner with this solution (you can regain logarithmic-time lookup by constructing a fake Node as a key for `set::find`, but it's still a little inelegant), and the object identity is slightly cleaner with the other solution.

Comment: I think if he just used `find` on the set, he'd also get the same performance, since usually both `set` and `map` are R&B trees.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned in the note at the bottom that you _can_ get the same lookup complexity - but having to construct a temporary Node for the key is a bit clunky